# App made with MahApps.Metro won't run on other computers

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mahapps.metro

I made a new version of my app with MahApps.Metro. I build the project for release, and copied the entire release folder to a flash drive to test on other machines.

The first machine had this config: **Windows 7 Home Premium 32-bit, .NET Framework 4.5**. After double clicking the app, nothing happens. The executable doesn't show up in task manager.

Then I tried a machine with **Windows 8.1 Preview** but it didn't run there either and didn't show up in the task manager.

It runs just fine on my dev machine running **Windows 8 Pro with Media Center**. Am I missing something? Is there something I need to do?

Comment: Did you finally solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the platform target to x86?

```
PROJECT -> Project Properties -> Build -> Platform target
```